# Beginner RPG for 2

Tags: game-recommendation, new-players, one-on-one

My girlfriend and I are pretty bored and are interested in playing a 2 player RPG. Doesn't matter if with GM or not. What are some good beginner RPGs for 2 people? Doesn't matter about subject or the genre!

Comment: Unfortunately, genre, scope, complexity, and theme do matter to us. Take a look at our [game-recommendation](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1070/are-game-recommendation-questions-on-topic/1071#1071) guidelines to get a sense of how to accurately ask your question.

Comment: There are some great two-player RPGs out there (Google can help lots on that score, BTW), but because we're a Q&A site with certain rules about how narrow recommendation questions need to be, to answer it here we'll need some more information to work with so we can narrow the field down to the right game for your situation.

Comment: I really hope you can revise your question, there's definitely some 2 player RPGs I can recommend that are great for beginners.